# Swift 3 JSON Bug?

Tags: json, swift

I can't seem to compile my code no matter how much I fiddle with it. I think I need another perspective.

At "let image = data["images"] as! [String : AnyObject]"

xcode keeps telling me "Cannot subscript a value of type '[[String : AnyObject]]' with an index of type 'String'"

```
func retreiveInstagramMedia() {
    let token = user?.token
    let urlString = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token=\(token!)"
    let url = URL(string: urlString)
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: {
        (data, response, error) in
        if(error != nil){
            print("error")
        }else{
            do{
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options:.allowFragments) as! [String : AnyObject]

                if let data = json["data"] as? [[String : AnyObject]] {
                        let image = data["images"] as! [String : AnyObject]
                        let standardResolution = image["standard_resolution"] as! [String : AnyObject]
                        let url = standardResolution["url"] as! String
                        print(url)


                }

                OperationQueue.main.addOperation({
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                })

            }catch let error as NSError{
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }).resume()
}
```

Comment: It is neither a Swift 3 nor a JSON bug. – `data` is an *array* of dictionaries. You already iterate over its entries, but for a reason unknown to me use the wildcard `_` as loop variable.

Comment: you get array or dictionary first check it. otherwise Use this https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON Easy handing json data.

Comment: @BHAVIKPANCHAL So I have to use [[String : AnyObject]] in order to print data

Comment: you get the value in json or not?

Comment: @BHAVIKPANCHAL Yes it is json

Comment: use https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Martin said, your `data` is an array of dictionaries. So iterate through those dictionaries:

```
if let arrayOfData = json["data"] as? [[String : Any]] {
    for individualData in arrayOfData {
        if let image = individualData["images"] as? [String : Any], 
            let standardResolution = image["standard_resolution"] as? [String : Any], 
            let url = standardResolution["url"] as? String {
                // now do something with URL
                print(url)
        }
    }
}
```

I'd suggest you avoid using `!` to force cast/unwrap. When dealing with data from remote sources, you should more gracefully handle situations where one of these subscripts fail to retrieve what you expect they would.

Answer (score 1):

First of all in Swift 3 a JSON dictionary is `[String:Any]`

Your mistake (developer bug) is to use the array `data` as the index variable of the loop.
Replace the underscore with `anItem` and get the image with `anItem["images"]`

```
   let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as! [String : Any]

    if let data = json["data"] as? [[String : Any]] {
        for anItem in data {
            let image = anItem["images"] as! [String : Any]
            let standardResolution = image["standard_resolution"] as! [String : Any]
            let url = standardResolution["url"] as! String
            print(url)
        }
    }
```

Note: The key `images` implies multiple items so the value could be also an array.

Comment: According to [the documentation](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/#get_users_media_recent_self), `images` is a dictionary, not an array.

Comment: @Rob Thanks for clarification. The naming is not intuitive.